# Error 400--Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8

I have this controller

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/books/store/product",
                  "/books/store/product/",
                  "/books/store/product/{productId}",
                  "/books/store/product/{productId}/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductForm productForm, 
                              @PathVariable Long productId,
            HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

..
}
```

Everything is fine for this URL  : `/books/store/product/232`

but for this one `/books/store/product/`

I got this error:

Error 400--Bad Request

```
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.
```

I've tried to put this  `@PathVariable(required = false)`, but I got a compilation error: `The attribute required is undefined for the annotation type PathVariable`

Comment: You should add @PathVariable(required=false)

Comment: it's better to separate it into two methods one with PathVariable and the other without, also no need to add "/" mappings, it's useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the service is always waiting for the path variable `productId`

Because you're using Spring 3 I suggest you to create 2 methods. One with the path variable and the other without it.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/books/store/product",
                  "/books/store/product/"}, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductForm productForm,
            HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

..
}

 @RequestMapping(value = { "/books/store/product/{productId}",
                  "/books/store/product/{productId}/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductForm productForm, 
                              @PathVariable Long productId,
            HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

..
}
```

If you're using Spring 4 and Java 8 I suggest you to use optional.

```
@PathVariable Optional<Long> productId
```

Comment: have to be this, anyway:  @PathVariable Optional<Long> productId

Comment: same problem :-(   how come?

Comment: This is because of the Spring version, Optional is for java 8 and Spring 4 and beyond. I suggest you to create 2 methods. One with the path variable and the other without the path variable. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not always need productId. Try using query parameter and make it optional. `required=false`

This url will now look like:

1. http://localhost:8080/books/store/product?productId=232
2. http://localhost:8080/books/store/product

Like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/books/store/product",
                   }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductForm productForm,
 @RequestParam(value = "productId", required = false) Long productId,
            HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

..
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alternatively, make two separate methods one with path variable and other without path variable.